# [PyQt]Open second window every time i push the button without closing the program

Tags: python, pyqt, subprocess, pyqt4

This is my main program. I run it and it opens me my main window with a pushbutton. When i push the button it opens me a second window. When i close the second window and push the button again, the second window won't open. I have to run the program again to work. How should I do to open my second window every time i press the button from the main window,without closing the main window/program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only call `show()` when  `Adauga_p_camera` is `None`. After the first click it is no longer `None`. You need to move the call to `show()` outside of the conditional.

```
def Adauga_p_camera(self):
    if self.Adauga_p_camera is None:
        self.Adauga_p_camera = Adauga_p_camera(self)

    self.Adauga_p_camera.show()
```

You also reuse the name `Adauga_p_camera` as the name of a class, method and instance variable. Not only is this confusing, but in the case of the latter 2 you are actually overwriting the method definition when you write `self.Adauga_p_camera=None`. You should assign each of these items a unique name to avoid any unintended behaviour.